# FastApi BasicAuth with cookies redirect problem

Tags: python, cookies, response, fastapi

every time I succesfully login and want to redirect to /welcome i get an error and don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
import secrets
from typing import Dict
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, status, Depends, Cookie, Form, Response, Request
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from fastapi.security import HTTPBasic, HTTPBasicCredentials
from hashlib import sha256

app = FastAPI()
security = HTTPBasic()
app.secret_key = "very constatn and random secret, best 64 characters"
app.sessions= []

@app.get("/welcome")
def welcome(request: Request, token = Cookie(None)):
    if token in app.sessions:
        return {"message": "No hej"}
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Login first")

@app.post("/login")
def Login(response: Response,credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(security)):
    correct_username = secrets.compare_digest(credentials.username, "root")
    correct_password = secrets.compare_digest(credentials.password, "toor")
    if (correct_username and correct_password):
        session_token = sha256(bytes(f"{credentials.username}{credentials.password}{app.secret_key}", encoding='utf8')).hexdigest()
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_302_FOUND
        response.set_cookie(key="session_token", value=session_token)
        app.sessions += session_token
        response.headers['Location'] = "/welcome"
        return response
    else:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect login or password",
        )
```

And here is the error message:

```
response.set_cookie(key="session_token", value=session_token)
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'set_cookie'
```

In /docs after logging in I get:

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

If I switch /login from POST to GET and after logging in it shows:

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["body","response"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I think using `RedirectResponse` in `fastapi.responses` works.

If I understand correctly what you're trying to accomplish, it's this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

And `RedirectResponse` allows this:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#redirectresponse

However, the default status code for `RedirectResponse` is `307`. This means if you make a `GET` request, the redirect will be a `GET` request too. And, if you make a `POST` request, the redirect will be a `POST` request as well. (I tested this.) If you change the code to `303`, though, the `POST` request will get turned into a `GET` request upon redirect.

I simplified your code, and the following seems to work:

```
app = FastAPI()
session_token = "abc"

@app.get("/welcome")
def welcome():
    return {"message": "No hej"}

@app.post("/login")
def Login():
    rr = RedirectResponse('/welcome', status_code=303)
    rr.set_cookie(key="session_token", value=session_token)
    return rr
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu server with gunicorn and uvicorn.  Everything was fine in HTTP.  When I added SSL certificate I then would get error in redirects.  Solved using @Michael Kennedy solution in FastAPI course code:

```
response = RedirectResponse('/main', status_code=status.HTTP_302_FOUND)
return response
```

If setting a cookie:

```
@api.get('/auth_cookie')
def auth_cookie(response: Response, val):
    '''set an auth cookie
    '''
    # IMPORTANT: httponly=True is important for server, but does not work localhost
    response.set_cookie(my_cookie, val, secure=False,
                httponly=False, samesite='Lax')

# then later, in your endpoint:
response = RedirectResponse('/main', status_code=status.HTTP_302_FOUND)
auth_cookie(response, access_token)
return response
```

This is a redirect to a get endpoint.  I do not believe this will work with a post.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. And I solve in this way with

```
    response_data = response_token.json()
    if response_data["token_type"] == 'Bearer':
        response = RedirectResponse(url="/whoami/", status_code=303)
        # Set cookies here
        response.set_cookie(key="token", value=response_data["token"], max_age= response_data["expires_in"], httponly=True, secure=True, samesite='Lax')
        return response
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Wrong authentication method")
```

**Important**

1. You need to Return same object from which you set Cookie
2. You should define redirection Response Before setting Cookie